# HTML to PDF in JavaScript (reactJS) with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jspdf

In my reactJS I want to convert my DOM (and a part) of my DOM into a PDF. I want a readable and selectable PDF and I don't want to loose my CSS styling.

I tried this:

```
const input = document.getElementById('toPdf');

let doc = new jsPDF("portrait", "mm", "a4");
doc.fromHTML(input, 1, 1);
doc.save("myDocument.pdf");
```

Thats nice. Its readable, Multipage and Text is selectable. But it looses the complete styling.

Result is:

[image]

Is there a way to keep the styling?

My HTML Looks like this:

[image]

I Use this: [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

Thanks in advance.

Update Errors:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: pdf is not defined
    at Object.callback (RaUpdateSendReportMethods.js?ea2d:54)
    at Promise.eval (jspdf.min.js?b003:118)
callback @ RaUpdateSendReportMethods.js?ea2d:54
(anonymous) @ jspdf.min.js?b003:118
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ jspdf.min.js?b003:118
y.thenCore @ jspdf.min.js?b003:118
y.then @ jspdf.min.js?b003:118
y.doCallback @ jspdf.min.js?b003:118
i.html @ jspdf.min.js?b003:118
createPDF @ RaUpdateSendReportMethods.js?ea2d:51
onClick @ RaUpdateSendReport.js?3ca0:238
EnhancedButton._this.handleClick @ EnhancedButton.js?7315:138
boundFunc @ ReactErrorUtils.js?dc41:63
ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback @ ReactErrorUtils.js?dc41:69
executeDispatch @ EventPluginUtils.js?5d8c:83
executeDispatchesInOrder @ EventPluginUtils.js?5d8c:106
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ EventPluginHub.js?0f32:41
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ EventPluginHub.js?0f32:52
forEachAccumulated @ forEachAccumulated.js?e2c3:22
processEventQueue @ EventPluginHub.js?0f32:252
runEventQueueInBatch @ ReactEventEmitterMixin.js?91f8:15
handleTopLevel @ ReactEventEmitterMixin.js?91f8:25
handleTopLevelImpl @ ReactEventListener.js?944f:70
perform @ Transaction.js?f15f:141
batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js?e9be:60
batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js?8e6b:95
dispatchEvent @ ReactEventListener.js?944f:145
html2canvas.min.js:7 html2canvas: Preload starts: finding background-images
html2canvas.min.js:7 html2canvas.Util.Children failed with exception: Cannot read property 'document' of null
html2canvas.min.js:7 html2canvas: Preload: Finding images
html2canvas.min.js:7 html2canvas: Preload: Done.
html2canvas.min.js:7 html2canvas: start: images: 0 / 0 (failed: 0)
html2canvas.min.js:7 Finished loading images: # 0 (failed: 0)
html2canvas.min.js:7 html2canvas: Renderer: Canvas renderer done - returning canvas obj
html2canvas.min.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 
'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'
    at html2canvas.min.js:8
    at Object.u.Renderer (html2canvas.min.js:8)
    at Object.o.complete (html2canvas.min.js:8)
    at o (html2canvas.min.js:7)
    at Object.u.Preload (html2can

vas.min.js:7)
at html2canvas.min.js:8
```

Comment: Look at this example and try it out -> https://www.codementor.io/amehjoseph/convert-html-css-content-to-a-sleek-multiple-page-pdf-file-using-jspdf-javascript-library-eyyz74hci

Comment: thanks but I can't see where is the difference that keeps the styling

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try jsPDF's `.html()` instead of [`.fromHtml()`](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/1176#issuecomment-419201926).

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js" 
        integrity="sha384-NaWTHo/8YCBYJ59830LTz/P4aQZK1sS0SneOgAvhsIl3zBu8r9RevNg5lHCHAuQ/"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="~/lib/html2canvas/html2canvas.min.js"></script></script>
<!-- html2canvas 1.0.0-alpha.11 up to v1.0.0-rc.1 works, current version may not work -->

<script>
    function download() {
        let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
        pdf.html(document.getElementById('toPdf'), {
            callback: function () {
                pdf.save('myDocument.pdf');
                window.open(pdf.output('bloburl')); // To debug.
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: can I pass a specific css file as well? to change some stuff from displayed version?

Comment: not yet can It test tomorrow ... Pc is at home only smartphone ;) ... I try it tomorrow morning

Comment: understand. You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54726120/4271117) about changing css. It has nothing to do with jspdf though, pure JavaScript.

Comment: when I do it like above I got errors I add them above

Comment: Now I got an new error `html2canvas.min.js:6 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'setEnd' on 'Range': The offset 24 is larger than the node's length (23).` any hint for me?

Comment: downvoting because .html is not found without perhaps building the lib and even though with problems. Not the right solution.